# How to capture PivotTableUpdate event in an excel file from an excel add-in?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an add-in which manipulates data in a specific excel file to generate a pivot table. I need to run a piece of code from this add-in when the pivot table is updated.

I would like to know how I can capture this event and trigger an action from the add-in.

I have seen discussions about it on other sites, but unfortunately I am not able to understand them. Please help me with an example, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this with the following code.

The following code was added to ThisWorkbook object of add-in

```
Dim RTMApp As New RTMEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set RTMApp.RTM_App = Application
End Sub
```

Then I added the following code to a new class named 'RTMEvents'

```
Public WithEvents RTM_App As Application

Private Sub RTM_App_SheetPivotTableUpdate(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Code.DoPercentageCalculation '(calling the macro to execute)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, within add-in code, add:

```
Dim WithEvents pivotsheet as Worksheet

...
'Somewhere in your code...
    Set  pivotsheet = ...
...

Private Sub pivotsheet_PivotTableAfterValueChange(ByVal TargetPivotTable As PivotTable, ByVal TargetRange As Range)
    'Action
End Sub
```